# "this" in functions belonging to an array

Tags: ecmascript-6, this

I have a ES6 class that contains a method with async.waterfall. Waterfall gets an array of functions as its first argument. So I do it this way:

```
class RequestLog {
    mainMethod() {
        async.waterfall([
            this.method1,
            this.method2,
            this.method3
        ]);
    }

    method1(cb) {
        console.log(this); // outputs null
        cb();
    }
}
```

But as noted above, in first function I nave `this === null`. If it was anon function I'd write:

```
async.waterfall([ (cb) => { console.log(this) } ]);
```

but I want to have separated methods for code clarity.
So, how do I pass `this` to named function inside a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to bind the methods to `this`. Here are some options:

**Option 1** - bind them when you use them:

```
mainMethod() {
    async.waterfall([
        this.method1.bind(this),
        this.method2.bind(this),
        this.method3.bind(this)
    ]);
}
```

**Option 2** - bind them in the constructor:

```
class RequestLog {
  constructor() {
    this.method1 = this.method1.bind(this);
    this.method2 = this.method2.bind(this);
    this.method2 = this.method3.bind(this);
  }
  ...
}
```

**Option 3** - bind them using [proposal-class-fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), which requires babel's [Class properties transform](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) or [Stage 2 preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/):

```
class RequestLog {
    method1 = (cb) => {
        console.log(this); // outputs null
        cb();
    }
}
```

**Option 4** - use [proposal-bind-operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator), which requires babel's [Function bind transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/):

```
mainMethod() {
    async.waterfall([
        ::this.method1,
        ::this.method2,
        ::this.method3
    ]);
}
```

**Option 5** - call them from an arrow function:

```
mainMethod() {
    async.waterfall([
        (cb) => this.method1(cb),
        (cb) => this.method2(cb),
        (cb) => this.method3(cb)
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, both concise and comprehensive. I chose the fifth option as it doesn't use `bind` (I hoped I'll never need it again thanks to ES6) and shows what parameters go to each function. Thanks a lot!